# Volume mounts not working with digital ocean

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

Small test case:

docker-compose.yml

```
nginx:
  image: nginx:1
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - ./testconf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    - ./testhtml:/usr/share/nginx/html
```

testconf/nginx.conf

```
server {
  listen        80;
  server_name _;

  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    try_files $uri $uri/;
  }
}
```

testhtml/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Hello</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

machine creation:

```
$ docker-machine create --driver digitalocean --digitalocean-access-token xxxx --digitalocean-region "ams3" edgee
```

pushing:

```
$ eval $(docker-machine env edgee)
$ docker-compose up
$ curl $(docker-machine ip edgee)
```

When I look inside the container the files which should be mounted just aren't there. This works locally, it works with machine and virtualbox, but it doesn't work with digitalocean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a wrong expectation as such. Your machine and your digital ocean doesn't share folders. When you have below in volumes

```
  volumes:
    - ./testconf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    - ./testhtml:/usr/share/nginx/html
```

And your current folder is `/user/name/projects` then doing `docker-compose up` with docker pointing to your digital ocean would tell the remote docker to map 
`/user/name/projects/testhtml` folder on digital ocean server to `/usr/share/nginx/html` inside container. There is no such folder on host so a blank folder will be created and shared.

Now the reason that it works on your local with virtualbox is the use of automated shared folders

[image: shared folders]

As you can see on my mac `/Users` is automatically shared. So any `docker-compose` project i launch which is present in `/Users` the volume sharing will automatically work. Because `/Users` from host is shared mounted on `/Users` inside the docker-machine VM. But if I move the project to some other folder that `/Users` then the behavior would be same as you see now with digital ocean.

So the only thing you can do is, either copy the files you want inside the Dockerfile during the build itself. Or copy the project on remote server and run it from there

Comment: I do the copy but it doesn't work either, I have COPY /folder /usr/src/app/folder in the Dockerfile but it does nothing.

Comment: You need to remove the mount from your compose file, else the mount will overshadow the folder inside container with a blank folder.

Comment: Removing the copy from the volumes did the trick I will add a new comment with the details.

Answer (score 1):

Tarun's answers lead me to better understand the issue. The way to solve it is to copy the files in the build, add this to your Dockerfile:

```
COPY local/path /path/in/server
```

In the docker-compose.yaml file add a volumes section to the web app service:

```
volumes:
  - /usr/src/app/donare/static
```

If like me you have an nginx service, take the volumes from the web app service to have the files served by nginx:

```
volumes_from:
  - web
```

Comment: Don't use `volumes_from` it is deprecated and not available in compose version 3. You should rather create a named volume and share the data using same

Comment: Thanks @TarunLalwani, I will do that!